# Simple mapReduce operation on strings

Tags: go

I have a list of strings

```
elems := [n]string{...}
```

I want to perform a simple mapReduce operation, such that I

1. Map every string to a different string, let's say `string -> $string`
2. Reduce all the strings to one string with a separator, e.g. `{s1, s2, s3} -> s1@s2@s3`

all in all: `{s1, s2, s3} -> $s1@$s2@$s3`

**What's the best way to do this?**

I'm looking for efficiency and readability

Bonus points if it's generic enough to work not only on strings

Comment: Do you need to preserve the sequence?

Comment: @KavehShahbazian yes

Answer (score 2):

For mapping just a list, you won't have much choice other than to go over each string. If the transform algo is time-consuming and you need speed, you can consider splitting the job and use a go routine. Finally you can use the strings.Join function which has an option to specify a separator, this normally performs the reduce part efficiently. The size of the dataset can also be a consideration, and for larger sized lists you may want to compare performance with strings.Join and your own customized algo and see if you want to use multiple go routines/channels to achieve what you want to.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to do the 2 things separately, the end result can be achieved simply by using `strings.Join()`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    a := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
    p := "$"
    fmt.Println(p + strings.Join(a[:], "@"+p))
}
```

prints `$a@$b@$c`

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eWVCIp-VTJ)

Comment: This is too specific, the transformation can be more complex than "$"+str

Answer (score 0):

Go is explicitly NOT a functional programming language.

You map and reduce using a for loop.

```
a := []string{"a", "b", "c"}
result := "initvalue"
for n, i := range a {
  result += i + string(n)
}
```

Comment: I agree. Go can support a functional programming style. See https://golang.org/doc/codewalk/functions. But it is not a functional programming language. +1 for making this clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not going to perform any sort of IO operations inside your *map* functions (means they are doing just some computations), making it concurrent would make it slower for sure and even if you are doing some IO, you should benchmark. Concurrency would not make things faster necessarily and some times add unnecessary complications. In many cases just a simple *for* loop is sufficient.

If the *map* functions here are IO bound or are doing some sort of computation heavy calculations that do benefit from going concurrent, solutions can vary. For example [NATS](http://nats.io) can be used to go beyond one machine and distribute the workload.

This is a relatively simple sample. Reduce phase is not multistage and is blocking:

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "sync"
    "testing"

    "github.com/stretchr/testify/assert"
)

type elem struct {
    index int
    value interface{}
}

func feed(elems []interface{}) <-chan elem {
    result := make(chan elem)
    go func() {
        for k, v := range elems {
            e := elem{
                index: k,
                value: v,
            }
            result <- e
        }
        close(result)
    }()
    return result
}

func mapf(
    input <-chan elem,
    mapFunc func(elem) elem) <-chan elem {
    result := make(chan elem)
    go func() {
        for e := range input {
            eres := mapFunc(e)
            result <- eres
        }
        close(result)
    }()
    return result
}

// is blocking
func reducef(
    input <-chan elem,
    reduceFunc func([]interface{}) interface{}) interface{} {
    buffer := make(map[int]interface{})
    l := 0
    for v := range input {
        buffer[v.index] = v.value
        if v.index > l {
            l = v.index
        }
    }
    data := make([]interface{}, l+1)
    for k, v := range buffer {
        data[k] = v
    }

    return reduceFunc(data)
}

func fanOutIn(
    elemFeed <-chan elem,
    mapFunc func(elem) elem, mapCount int,
    reduceFunc func([]interface{}) interface{}) interface{} {
    MR := make(chan elem)
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < mapCount; i++ {
        mapResult := mapf(elemFeed, mapFunc)

        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            for v := range mapResult {
                MR <- v
            }
        }()
    }
    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(MR)
    }()
    return reducef(MR, reduceFunc)
}

func Test01(t *testing.T) {
    elemFeed := feed([]interface{}{1, 2, 3})
    finalResult := fanOutIn(
        elemFeed,
        func(e elem) elem {
            return elem{
                index: e.index,
                value: fmt.Sprintf("[%v]", e.value),
            }
        },
        3,
        func(sl []interface{}) interface{} {
            strRes := make([]string, len(sl))
            for k, v := range sl {
                strRes[k] = v.(string)
            }
            return strings.Join(strRes, ":")
        })
    assert.Equal(t, "[1]:[2]:[3]", finalResult)
}
```

And since it uses `interface{}` as the element type, it can get generalized.